# Parsing JSON-file with Python in Django

Tags: python, json, django, django-views

I have query where I fetch JSON-file and want to show the data in table in HTML. I get now error: **TypeError: string indices must be integers** in line: 'status': item['status'],. Is the problem with outer brackets, because they are missing in json or what?

**views.py code**

```
json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = json.load(json_obj)
results = []
for item in data:
    results.append({
        'status': item['status'],
        'device': item['device'],
       })
return render(request, 'index/index.html', {'objects_list': results})
```

**JSON-file:**

```
{
  “version": “3.62”,
  "treesize": 2,
  "": [
    {
      “status”: “up”,
      "device": “someDeviceName1”,
    }
    {
      “status”: “up”,
      "device": “someDeviceName2”,
    }]
}
```

Comment: `data` is the dictionary with three elements: `"version"`, `"treesize"`, and `""`.

Comment: `json.load(json)` makes no sense. Is your input really stored in the variable `json`?

Comment: What DisplayName said.  `json = urllib2.urlopen(url)` binds the name `json` to the URL handle, so it no longer refers to the `json` module.

Comment: @DisplayName No really. I'll edit it to question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether you accidentally copied the JSON content wrong or not but what you should do is:

```
>>> for item in data[""]:
...     results.append({ ...
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was missing. Maybe I just was confused, that the array don't have name.

Comment: adding read() to response gives me an error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Added this to correct answer as this works, when I added data[""] to my original code in views.py.

Comment: Or, with a list comprehension :)